# Call a function inside an unknown class that extends a known class

Tags: c++

As the title says I have the following "base" class that user can extend:

```
class BaseScene
{
private:
    bool sceneloop = false;

public:
    virtual void Start();
    virtual void EventHandler(SDL_Event event);
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();

    void _toggleLoopMode() { sceneloop = !sceneloop; }
    bool _sceneloop() { return sceneloop; }

};
```

My problem is I can't know what name, the user, choose for his classes so how I can call a known method (like Start or EventHandler) from my main class inside an unknown class?

An example of a class that is unknown to me but well-known to the user can be:

```
class SomeFunnyRandomName : public BaseScene
{
public:
    void Start();
    void Eventhandler(SDL_Event event);
    void Update();
    void Draw();
};
```

So form the main class I need to call Start() inside "SomeFunnyRandomName" without:

```
SomeFunnyRandomName sfrn = new SomeFunnyRandomName();
```

If you can include the code it will be very helpful (but not required).

Comment: Use a virtual method?

Comment: I need to call a class when I don't know the name. My code needs to work without doing "NameClass class = new NameClass();" It must be dynamic so the user can pass his class and I use that object. I don't know if I explained correctly in the post. In case let me know so I can add more information.

Comment: Maybe show the code you're trying to implement?

Comment: The problem is I don't know what code to implement. I think that I need to use "template<typename T>" but I've never tried to do something like this before and I haven't found anything on the Internet so I don't know to proceed.

Comment: It doesn't need to work (if you knew how to do it then you wouldn't have a question) just show what you want your code to look like

Comment: `SomeFunnyRandomName sfrn; sftrn.Start()` should work as your code is at the moment, I still don't understand what you want to do

Comment: You cannot "call a class". You can only call a function. If you want to create an object of an unknown class provided by your user, you need to call a function *provided by your user* which creates an object of that class and returns a pointer to it. It is however not clear why you need to create objects of unknown classes at all. Please show your use case.

Comment: What I need to is like modular programming: My user extends his class to my class as in the example (SomeFunnyRandomName) but I don't know the name of the classes. The only thing that I know is the following: The user's class contains the method (Start(), Update(), etc...). And I want to call that class without knowing the name of the user's classes like:
// pseudo-code
function call(class: users_class) {
   users_class->start();
}

Comment: Let me reiterate. You cannot "call a class", there's no such thing in C++ as calling a class. You can only call a function. Is it clear up to this point?

Comment: yes, it's clear.

Comment: Great. Now, since you don't ever call a class, only a function, you don't need to name a class when calling a function (unless it's a static member function, but you don't need such things here). So when do you need to name a class? When you create an object of that class. I don't see where you might need to create objects. There is a single object, created by your user, whose class inherits `BaseScene`. You only need a pointer or a reference to that object in order to call its member functions.

Comment: (cont'd) In all non-static member functions of `BaseScene`, there is a pointer to that object, it's called `this`. So you can call member functions on `this`. If the function is virtual, it will call the correct function in your user's class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take a reference or pointer to `BaseScene`, and call the methods on that. The caller passes an instance of their derived class.

```
class UsesScene {
    BaseScene & scene;
public:
    UsesScene(BaseScene & scene) : scene(scene) {}

    void doStuff() { scene.Start(); scene.Update(); }
    /*... etc*/ 
};

int main() {
    SomeFunnyRandomName scene;
    UsesScene usesScene(scene);
    usesScene.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, this, cannot solve my problem. In my case isn't the user that calls BaseScene but it's my code that calls the user class that extends the base class. (es. my code -> user_class : BaseScene) And my problem is that I don't know how to accept an unknown class and call a known method (es. UserScene in my unknown class, Start() is my known method)

Comment: @user13767094 I think you misread the answer: `UsesScene` (not `UserScene`) is the code on your side, and it only know `BaseScene`. `SomeFunnyRandomName`, the user's type, only appears in `main` on the user's side.

Comment: @Quentin I've tried your solution but I can access only to my BaseScene function, not the SomeFunnyRandomName function. If I print "Hello" inside SomeFunnyRandomName::Start() and "Hi" inside BaseScene::Start() your code run only the second one, not the first one.

Comment: @Pinnaker [really?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76ed2abe4eae5d29)